# Query error: Column cannot be null - Invalid query

Tags: php, codeigniter

im use code php in method get to post in column 'tr_no_hp'
like

```
$nomorhp = $this->input->get('nomor_hp');
```

but after i try to insert in database column cant be null.
how to fix this problems

this my controllers code

```
$nomorhp = $this->input->get('nomor_hp');
$data = array(
                    'us_id' => $this->user->us_id,
                    'sv_id' => $voucher->sv_id,
                    'op_id' => $voucher->op_id,
                    'tr_id_plgn' => $nomor,
                    'tr_no_hp' => $nomorhp,


                );

                 $this->db->insert('transaksi', $data);
                 $trx_id =$this->db->insert_id();
```

and i got this eror code

```
Query error: Column 'tr_no_hp' cannot be null - Invalid query: INSERT INTO `transaksi`
```

thanks

Comment: What type is the `tr_no_hp` column? What PHP version are you running?

Comment: type is varchar(16) and i use PHP 5.6

Comment: Assign default value of 'tr_no_hp' column to NULL

Comment: can u tell me more detail code  default value of 'tr_no_hp' column to NULL

Comment: in your database this 'tr_no_hp' column has not default value null and $nomorhp = $this->input->get('nomor_hp'); your this code get nothing check what data sending

Comment: @yagamicell , check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57830009/query-error-column-cannot-be-null-invalid-query/57831283#57831283

Answer (score 1):

Assign default value of `'tr_no_hp'` column to `NULL` in phpmyadmin

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can either modify you tables to allow null (but this might break other things) or set a default value.

For example:

```php
$nomorhp = $this->input->get('nomor_hp') ?: ''; // Default to empty string
```